# Align the Images properly

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Hi I am trying to get the handwritten data only from an image, for that I took a empty image and a filled one and then I am doing ImageChops.difference to get the data out of it.
The problem is right now with the alignment of images, both are not equally aligned in terms of depth, so the results are not correct.

from PIL import Image, ImageChops

```
def compare_images(path_one, path_two, diff_save_location):
    """
    Compares to images and saves a diff image, if there
    is a difference

    @param: path_one: The path to the first image
    @param: path_two: The path to the second image
    """
    image_one = Image.open(path_one).convert('LA')
    image_two = Image.open(path_two).convert('LA')

    diff = ImageChops.difference(image_one, image_two)
    if diff.getbbox():
        diff.convert('RGB').save(diff_save_location)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    compare_images('images/blank.jpg',
                   'images/filled.jpg',
                   'images/diff.jpg')
```

This is the result which I got.
[image]

the result which I am looking for:
[image]

Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: You have some fixed template for the image, this means you have the coordinate information of the handwritten texts, then you can use the coordinate information to crop the handwriiten text areas.

Comment: The term to search for is *"Image Registration"*. If you look at the grids on the left side of your image you'll see they are much more horizontally displaced from each other than on the right side of the image which means you have *"bad stuff"* going on as well as normal displacements - e.g. your scan may not be flat. This is beyond Pillow's capabilities and you'll likely need to look to OpenCV. Look here at `ORB` and friends https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html#py-table-of-content-feature2d

Comment: Could you post links to the `filled.jpg` and `filled.jpg` images?

Answer (score 0):

This site may be helpful: https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/ .  The main idea is to first detect keypoints use SIFT, SURF or other algorithms in both images; then match the keypoints from the empty image with the keypoints from the handwritten image, to get a homography matrix; then use this matrix to align the two images.

After image alignment, post processing may be needed due to illumination or noise.